# The Vandermonde determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field.
Let $n$ be a natural number. For $n + 1 $ elements of $\mathbb{K}$, $x_0, ..., x_n$, we denote by $V (x_0, ..., x_n)$ the matrix in $\mathcal{M}_{n + 1} (\mathbb{K})$ defined by

$$
   V (x_0, ..., x_n) =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & x_0&x_0^2&...&x_0^n \\
    1 & x_1&x_1^2&...&x_1^n \\
    1 & x_2&x_2^2&...&x_2^n \\
    \vdots & \vdots&\vdots&...&\vdots \\
    1 & x_n&x_n^2&...&x_n^n \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$$
I want to show that : $$\det(V (x_0, ..., x_n))=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_j-x_i)$$.

I found, from a calculation, a recursive formula $$\det(V (x_0, ..., x_n))=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_n-x_i)\det(V (x_0, ..., x_{n-1}))$$
Then  $$\det(V (x_0, ..., x_n))=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(x_k-x_i)$$ How can i show that
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(x_k-x_i)=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_j-x_i)$$

Comment: I think you have an off by one error, as you have indexed your $x_i$ for $i \in \{0,\ldots, n\}$ as opposed to the usual indexing of $i \in \{1,\ldots, n +1\}$. For this reason you must alter the bound in your product to be $0 \leq i <j \leq n$ instead of $1 \leq i < j \leq n + 1$. I.e. you are already done

Comment: So what you want to show is actually $\det(V (x_0, ..., x_n))=\prod_{0\leq i<j\leq n}(x_j-x_i)$

Comment: after the correction proposed by @user2628206 you can see that if you fix $j=k$ on the right product for $1 \leq k \leq n$ you obtain $\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (x_k-x_i)$ so...